# How to synchronize files added in Firebase Storage based on collection ID?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a form in which user can fill many inputs, including add pictures. By state, i control every input and use this block of code to send the form to a firebase collection:

```
    try {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "protocols"), {
        name: name,
        gender: gender,
        age: age,
        duration: duration,
        initial: initial,
        finalWeight: finalWeight,
        strategy: strategy,
        height: height,
        kcal: kcal,
        protocol: compoundArray,
        description: description,
        initialBf: initialBf,
        finalBf: finalBf,
        user: { name: auth.currentUser.displayName, id: auth.currentUser.uid },
        createdAt: createdAt,
      });
```

However, firebase upload files to firestore, so, this is my code.

```
const uploadFiles = async (images) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      const imageRef = ref(
        storage,
        `/images/${username}/${getTimestampInSeconds()}`
      );
      try {
        await uploadBytes(imageRef, images[i]);
        
        console.log("success");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error:", error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Whenever i submit my form, files are upload just fine, but i can't refer the uploaded file to the correspondent form.

I tried creating a state in uploadFiles function and then add it to the collection, but its meaningless. I supposed i should use getDownloadURL of each image inside the array and pass as state inside the addDoc?

Comment: *I supposed i should use getDownloadURL of each image inside the array and pass as state inside the addDoc?* - Why don't you go ahead and give that a try? We can't really tell you what your app is supposed to do - you should tell us what you are trying to do and share with us what's not working the way you expect.